# Adding a grayscale mask during Compose Over using Imagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert

I have the following script ImageMagick script

```
convert $tmpA4 \
    \( -clone 0 -negate \) \
    \( -size ${wd}x${ht} gradient: -negate \) \
    -compose over -composite \
    $tmpA4
```

Which I am trying to regenerate using Imagick but ended without any luck. Please find the code which I tried

```
    $negate = clone($tmpA4);
    $negate->negateImage(false);
    file_put_contents("negateR.png",$negate);


    $gradient = new Imagick();       
    $gradient->newPseudoImage(round($wd),round($ht), "gradient:white-black"); 
    $gradient->setImageFormat("png");
    $gradient->negateImage(false);
    file_put_contents("gradientR.png",$gradient);

    $negate->setImageAlphaChannel(imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_OPAQUE);
    $negate->compositeimage($gradient, Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY , 0, 0);

    $tmpA4->setImageCompose(imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER);
    $tmpA4->compositeimage($negate, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
```

the negateR.png and gradientR.png are perfectly getting generated but the final composition doesn't.

[image]

[image]

Comment: try `imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_DEACTIVATE` rather than `imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_OPAQUE`. Why do you need `    $gradient->negateImage(false);`? I do not know Imagick that well to understand that line. It should be OK, since the gradient is grayscale.

Comment: I am not sure why you have `$tmpA4->setImageCompose(imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER);`, since you use COMPOSITE_OVER in the next command. But as I said above, I am not expert at Imagick.

Comment: When I do the  negate->setImageAlphaChannel( imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_DEACTIVATE  );

I get

Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: Unable to set image alpha channel in /home5/eshoppe4/public_html/imarasoft/rinsad/DazzVisualizer/mug/cylinderize.php:305 Stack trace: #0 /home5/eshoppe4/public_html/imarasoft/rinsad/DazzVisualizer/mug/cylinderize.php(305): Imagick->setimagealphachannel(4) #1 {main} thrown in /home5/eshoppe4/public_html/imarasoft/rinsad/DazzVisualizer/mug/cylinderize.php on line 305

Comment: try setImageMatte(...).

Comment: That doesn't work either

Comment: I'm unsure what exactly you're trying to achieve or how it "doesn't generate" - but maybe https://phpimagick.com/Tutorial/imagickComposite would help. Or you could clarify what is the difference between what you are expecting and what you are seeing.